# Error: .get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to node & express and I tried different variations and couldn't figure out why.  If I map app.get ('/') to just contentHandler then it works fine.  But if I map app.get ('/) to contentHandler.displayWelcomePage then I get the above error.  Thanks for looking.

Here is my structure:
app.js

routes/index.js

routes/content.js

```
app.js
    var express = require('express')
    ,   app = express()
    ,   routes = require('./routes')  
    ,   http = require('http')
    ,   path = require('path')
    ,   mongoose = require ('mongoose')
    ,   db = mongoose.connection
    ;

    db.on ('error', console.error);

    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    app.use (app.router);

    routes(app, db);  

    http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
        console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
    });
```

routes/index.js

```
var contentHandler = require('./content');

//this is what I need to add, see my notes below var aHandler = new contentHandler();
module.exports = exports = function (app, db) {
  console.log ('inside routes/index.js');
 app.get ('/', contentHandler.displayWelcomePage);
 //instead of using contentHandler, use aHandler.displayWelcomePage
};
```

routes/content.js

```
function contentHandler (req, res, db) {
console.log ('Inside contentHandler');

res.render('index', {layout: false, title: "Jade is three."});


this.displayWelcomePage = function (req, res) {
      return res.render('index', {layout: false, title: "Welcome to Jade"});

};

};

module.exports = contentHandler;
```

Comment: Well, you are exporting the function `contentHandler`, and that function doesn't have a method `displayWelcomePage`. You are only assigning a function to `this.displayWelcomePage` when `contentHandler` is executed, however, you are never executing it. Also, it's impossible to tell what value `this` will have if we don't know how you want to call it. This has nothing to do with node.js or express, but with basic JavaScript. I recommend to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions and

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  I thought by doing this app.get ('/', contentHandler.displayWelcomePage) I call the displayWelcomePage.

Comment: I solve the problem, I need to declare another variable in routes/index.js  var contentHandler = require('./content'); 
var aHandler = new contentHandler();

module.exports = exports = function (app, db) {
  console.log ('inside routes/index.js');
  app.get ('/', aHandler.displayWelcomePage);
};